# How to unit test Windows 8 phone or Windows client library?

Tags: windows, unit-testing, windows-8, windows-phone, client-library

I created a solution where I develop a client library for Windows 8 phone (containing a bunch of utility and helper classes). Most classes in the library are not public and I don't want them to be exposed in the library. There are only a few classes which in turn use other classes that are not public.

I wanted to unit test each and every class I wrote and I created another project by right-clicking solution and then "Add->New Project->Windows Phone Unit Test App". The unit test app got created fine with:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;



namespace MyClientLibraryTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now in the unit test app I wanted to refer to my client library and I added the client library DLL to the test project.

When I try to see something like:

MyClientLibrary.Foo where Foo is not a public class it is not visible in the test method TestMethod1().

I thought as the client library and the unit test project are in the same solution, they are visible.

As the non public classes in the client library are not visible and I am not sure if I am doing it the right way.

Need some guidance from .Net developers on this as I started coding .Net and Windows 8 phone very recently.

My question is not just related to Windows 8 phone client library.

Let's say I write a client library to be distributed, how do I unit test it?

How do I make sure that all classes are unit tested?

Am I doing the right way to create a unit test project or do I have to write the unit test within the client library itself and not outside in a new project?

Thanks for your time...

Have a good day!

Comment: Why test private methods? They are implementation details that are used by your public interface at the end. You should just make sure your public interface is well tested. Also test projects should typically be separate projects.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows Phone